# PHP - Find string in an Object

Tags: php, string, object

Want to find a string in an object, found this code online, but doesn't seem to work off-the-shelf, so to speak:

```
private static function in_object($val, $obj) {
    if($val == ""){
        trigger_error("in_object expects parameter 1 must not empty", E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    if(!is_object($obj)){
        $obj = (object)$obj;
    }

    foreach($obj as $key => $value){
        if(!is_object($value) && !is_array($value)){
            if(strpos($value,$val)!==FALSE){
                return true;
            }
        }elseif(is_array($value)) {
           if(in_array($val, $value)!==FALSE){
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            return self::in_object($val, $value);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It does not return an error message, the screen simply stays blank. The object I am searching will include arrays, and it is one of the arrays that I want test for certain text strings.

Was hoping this had a minor error and could be easily fixed.  Or perhaps some other solution?

Comment: The class has to implement the `Iterator` interface. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what doesn't work - do you get an error message? Or is there a specific example you can give where the result is not what you expect/want? (Please edit the question and add the details, don't just post them as comments.)

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this, as a kind of work around.

```
$string_to_find = 'find_me';

foreach ($obj as $property => $value) {
    if ($property == $string_to_find) {
        // You found the string 
        $found_string = $property;
    }
    if ($value == $string_to_find) {
        // You found the string
        $found_string = $value;
    }
}
```

This will find it either on the property or value. You should add in some error handling to prevent issues if you aren't 100% sure that you will always be using this on a valid object.